# how to find IDs of forms generated by Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-testing, django-tests

I'm writing tests for my django site and am wanting to select the login form generated by allauth using something like:

```
login_form = self.browser.find_element_by_id('login_form')
```

but I don't know how to find its class/id or any other way to select it.

I'm asking not so much for the answer to this specific question, but more asking how I can find the id's of things generated by allauth and similar packages so I can write tests for them in the future.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just inspect the html in your browser?

Comment: All it tells me is that the form's method is post

Comment: If it doesn't have an id then you will have to select it some other way. There is more than likely only 1 form tag on the page so you could use `self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form')`

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thank you